# Can't get ubuntu 12.04 to set pixel resolution higher than 1360x768

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

Can't get ubuntu 12.04 to set pixel resolution higher than 1360x768. Very new to linux liking it other than this lol. I have a dell xps 420 with a nvidia geforce 260 hooked up to my 55 inch tv through a dvi/hdmi adapter.The display program wont set the resolution above 1360x768.I have tried the two "additional driver" options for the graphics card and the Details Window doesn't recognise with either  driver.

Answer (score 0):

0pen `gnome-display-properties` from the dash or in a Terminal. There you could choose the resolution that fits your needs.